# How to click button inside Activity to change CustomeView item attributes

Tags: android

I have an activity which contains one button and one RecyclerView. The RecyclerView is done by the standard way - AdapterView and ViewHolder(inner class for the Adapter).

Inside the ViewHolder I have an image and text on CardView.

I want to show/hide the image inside the CardView,inside the ViewHolder by clicking the button in my Activity Class.

However I cannot figure it how - I cannot instantiate ViewHolder are access it as static.
When I instantiate the Adapter and call notifyItemChange() it also does not work.

Any help on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different approaches:

- [GreenRobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or any other even bus. Dispatch an event from the button click; and any card cell will listen and show/hide depending of the event
- every cell view holder would need a model (similar to array of items for a ListView). This model may have a boolean `showImage(true/false)`

  - when button is clicked, iterate through the array of models calling `Model.showImage(true)`
  - after updating every mode, call [Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())
  - in [Recycler.onBindViewHolder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#bindViewHolder(VH, int)) get a reference for the model of that position and show/hide the image based on the model boolean behind `Model.showImage()`